# Hibernate как замапить словарь из БД, OneToOne

Tags: spring, hibernate, kotlin, boot

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно настроить маппинг для следующей ситуации.
Дано две таблицы News и NewsStatus, при этом NewsStatus является просто словариком статусов, который заполняется руками. У меня получается так, что при вставке в News добавляется строка и в NewsStatus.

Сущность для новостей:

```
  @Entity @Table(name = "news")
    data class News (

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
    "news_seq")
    val id: Long = 0,

    val title: String? = null,

    val text: String? = null,

    val tag: String? = null,

    var create_user: String? = null,

    var create_date: Date? = null,

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "news_id", cascade = [CascadeType.REMOVE], fetch = 
    FetchType.LAZY,orphanRemoval = true)
    private val files: List<MyFile> = emptyList(),

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    @JoinColumn(name = "status_id")
    private val status: NewsStatus? = null
```

)

Сущность для статусов:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "news_type")
    data class NewsStatus (

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
    "status_seq")
    val status_id: Long = 1,

    val type: String? = "draft"
```

)

При добавлении строки в таблицу с новостями, строка добавляется и в таблице News_type. Я понимаю, почему так происходит, но не знаю как сделать, чтобы я мог при добавлении строки в таблицу News указывать id из таблицы NewsStatus и при селекте получать статус новости в виде текста. 
Фактически необходимо средствами Hibernate реализовать следующий сценарий:

```
 NSERT INTO News(news_id,..., status_id)
 VALUES (..., 1);

 NSERT INTO News(news_id,..., status_id)
 VALUES (..., 1);
```

И далее при селекте просто джоинить текстовое значение по status_id.

Comment: А что вы кладёте в поле `status`, неужели свежесозданный объект без `status_id`? По-моему вы должны загружать необходимый вам экземпляр `NewsStatus` и использовать в новом экземпляре `News` именно его. Тогда Hibernate будет считать, что это не новый объект и соответственно не будет создавать новую запись. Так же я бы убрал анотацию `@GeneratedValue` над полем `status_id` и прописал бы эту колонку в таблице как `NOT NULL`, ведь вы всегда прописываете это id в базе данных руками. Таким образом вы можете предотвратить случайное создание новых записей из вашего кода.

Comment: Добрый день! Спасибо за Ваш ответ, на самом деле мне просто надо было, чтобы при записи была возможность вставлять числовые значения и затем при селекте из БД автоматически бы подставлялось текстовое значение справочника в соответствии с id.

Comment: Вам это помогло?